# Better structured oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Within an Oracle 11 database, I have 2 tables (CAR and CAR_BRAND):

CAR has the following

```
car_id  |brand
1       |Audi
2       |BMW
3       |VW
```

CAR_BRAND has the following

```
brand
Audi
Bmw
```

It is straightforward to use a INNER JOIN to join on both tables

```
select c.* from car c
inner join car_brand cb on cb.brand = c.brand;
```

I have a requirement that when the CAR_BRAND table is empty, then to select all records within CAR otherwise select * from CAR joined with the CAR_BRAND table.

This can be done as the following:

```
SELECT c.* FROM car c JOIN car_brand cb ON cb.brand = c.brand
UNION ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM car c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT c.* FROM car c JOIN car_brand cb ON cb.brand = c.brand
);
```

This works fine, however, Is there a better, more efficient SQL to get the end result rather than using a UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to count the *car_brand* records as you retrieve the cars and then test for the two cases with a `or`:

```
select     car_id, brand
from       (
                select     c.*, 
                           cb.brand as match_brand, 
                           @r := @r + if(cb.brand is null,0,1)
                from       car c
                cross join (select @r := 0) init
                left join  car_brand cb
                        on cb.brand = c.brand
           ) base
where      @r = 0 or match_brand is not null
```

Comment: Maybe I\`m wrong but I think the OP wants an inner join if there are records in the second table. Didn\`t downvote.

Comment: I doubt this is not what the OP wants, the requirement is to join only when there is data in CAR_BRAND table, else dont do a join.Your query will always return all the records from the CAR table, irrespective of CAR_BRAND table,
Case: When there is x rows in Car table and 2 records in CAR_BRAND table. Your query will return 3 rows, while OP needs 2. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Mihai is correct in that an inner join is required if there are records in the second table. The UNION ALL does the job, so have decided to go with that approach. Hoped that there would be a short hand SQL as an alternative, but probably not. Thanks

Comment: @AlanaThoms, did you try the `left join` SQL I proposed? I claim that it produces the same records as you get with the `union all` query, but more efficiently.

Comment: @trincot, thanks for the response. The `left join` is successful when the CAR_BRAND table is not populated, however, when a row is inserted within the CAR_BRAND table, the query will still return all values.